# i keep on getting the 1064 error in mysql while trying to create the table

Tags: mysql, parsing, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

```
CREATE TABLE company.employee(

     'fname' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     'mname' CHAR NULL,
     'lname' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     'ssn' CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
     'bdate' DATE,
     'Address' VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
     'Sex' CHAR NULL,
     'Salary' DECIMAL (10,2) NULL,
     'Super_ssn' CHAR(9) NULL,
     'Dnumber' INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY('ssn')
     )
```

Error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''fname' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 'mname' CHAR NULL,
 'lname' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 '' at line 2   0.016 sec
```

Comment: 'The CHAR and VARCHAR types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store'  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html You have some char without size.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't put the column names in single quotes. Use backticks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks